# Synchronise contents to Orchard CMS from another source - regularly

Tags: orchardcms

I have a commerce system with products in it. The products are categorised and also have groups of attributes.

I’d like to **Synchronise/Update** the products from the commerce system to a content type of product items defined in Orchard so that the data is pushed to the Orchard content items from the commerce system.

My current thinking is to use Contrib.Taxonomies to represent the categories and the attributes of the products.

The ProductCategory taxonomy will be used as a commerce menu on the site.

The Orchard site will be one channel for the commerce system and all the information about the products has been defined in the commerce system and will only be managed by the commerce system.

Therefore, after synchronisation the Orchard site should represent the commerce product data.

So, any suggestions on...

What would be the best approach to synchronise the taxonomies and the products between the Orchard content DB and the commerce system so that Orchard reflects the commerce systems products in categories as product content types in a ProductCategory taxonomy?

I have been looking at the Import/Export module and wondering if I should write a more specific implementation to meet my requirements.
If so, where would I start?
If not, what should I do?

(BTW Loving the potential of Orchard CMS!!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a great module to build. I would definitely base it on the import/export feature. You should start by digging into its code. The potential of that feature goes far beyond importing and exporting xml files. The way it handles identity for example makes it very suitable for a synchronization feature. I hope this helps.

Comment: To add to what Bertrand has said, if you already have a module to list products (or if it's a custom type), you should be able to add a module that plugs into the scheduling service, pulls commerce data from wherever, and creates the new items.

Comment: OK so its to the import/export module I go. Thanks Gents.