# Orchard categorised/taxonomies and associated ContentItem housekeeping

Tags: orchardcms

A part of my Orchard site will be synchronised from an external source (commerce).
It will manage all aspect of category and products.

All other content will be manage only by Orchard.

I need to create a comprehensive synchronisation of the 2 systems.

[Background to the question can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689019/synchronise-contents-to-orchard-cms-from-another-source-regularly)

I need to;

1. Add content to Orchard which does not exist
2. Remove content which is no longer relevant
3. Move/Associate content to another Taxonomy term

My problem is Orchards Related/Associated content integrity is a bit of a mystery to me.

I have run into a couple of issues and I believe my conventional understanding of relational database integrity and its "[impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch)" (if you know what it mean) with the Orchard CMS idea of Related/Associated ContentItems.

What happens when I remove a ContentItem only to add the "same" ContentItem sometime down the line and associate it to a category which it had before?

e.g.

1. "Page1" is associated with taxonomy term "c" which is the leaf of
   "a","b","c"
2. I Sync.
3. I need to now remove "c" as it is redundant.
4. I Sync again.
5. Taxonomy term "c" is back but it is now a leaf of "d"
6. "Page1" is still part of term "c"

But is this now a new "c" and if so in what has made it unique from  old "c"?

Do I need to disassociate the contentItems from "c" prior to removing it so as to remove any conventional "foreign key" relationship?

There is a lot about how parts are attached to each other to create content types but what about the relationships which are implied by association?

What are the concepts we need to understand to make relational associations?

I'm sure that you can get a feel for the sorts of clarity I'm seeking as the question probably touches on a number of concepts fundamental to Orchard.

I'm sure that once I have completed the module for synchronisation all will be clear but at the moment I don't want to go on large assumptions as assumptions are the mother of all cock ups!!